# Is there a way to create a scrollbox that scrolls exactly one element at a time in UE4?

Tags: unreal-engine4

So I am trying to create a scroll box of sorts that holds some images. I know I can just but them inside of a scroll box but, is there a way to make it basically scroll one whole unit at a time? So what I don't want is to scroll and then it stops halfway between images if that makes sense. Does anyone know if this is possible. I'm doing this on mobile if that helps anyone out any. I want to get away from a button press and let the user scroll with their fingers left and right to go to the next image.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in UScrollBox called `ScrollWidgetIntoView`.

Perhaps you can use this to scroll to the next child of your scroll box each time.

Here is the API reference:
[UScrollBox::ScrollWidgetIntoView](https://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/UMG/Components/UScrollBox/ScrollWidgetIntoView/index.html)

There is also a variable that might be of some use called `DesiredScrollOffset` that can be set, [here](https://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/UMG/Components/UScrollBox/DesiredScrollOffset/index.html).